# How can overwrite objects that have the same key in updating State with state hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, use-state

I want to update the state when new filters are selected. the initial state shows the object structure i am aiming for. for example, i add a filter selection (for example "f2"), the label is fixed per filter, so we can neglect it, but the value maybe "va". Thats works fine, but when i want to change the value for "f2" to "vb", i now have two entries in my state {"f2":"va"} and {"f2":"vb"}, while i would rather have the first one  overwritten by the second.

```
 const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useState([{"f1":["l","v"]}]);

 const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
   setFilterValues([
     ...filterValues,
     {[filter]: [label, value]}
   ]);
 };
```

i tried callin setFilterValues twice (once with mapping the entries to my condition) to solve the problem, but then i didnt even update state at all:

```
 const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
    setFilterValues([
      ...filterValues,
      {[filter]: [label, value]}
    ]);
    let key = filter
    setFilterValues(
      filterValues.map(
        el => el.key == key?  { [key]: [label, value] } : el
      )
    )
  };
```

i am a little bit new to react, so maybe i dont get a fundamental thing with updating state in functional components. can anybody help me with this? thank you!

Comment: Would you be open to an approach that stores your filters in an array, and not array of objects?

Comment: that would be an array of arrays then? yes sure, i could work with that, i think.

Comment: What you’re doing is you’re adding a new filter with the same filter and values so you will get duplicates. Try to console.log filters before every return (render) to see what I mean. What you want to do is find the index of the element with the same key, remove it from the array and add the new one. You have to do all this without mutating the array. I suggest using a map instead though. Either way up to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Storing your filter array label-value pairs by key in an object (i.e. a "Map" or "Dictionary"), not an array, allows you constant time (O(1)) lookup by key to update the value of the filter by key (*copying and returning a new state value is OFC still O(n)*).

Also, use a functional state update to correctly access previous state and queue up state updates.

```
const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useState({ f1: ["l","v"] });

const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
  setFilterValues(prevFilterValues => ({
    ...prevFilterValues,  // copy previous state
    [filter]: [label, value], // set the value for filter key
  }));
};
```

Example:

```
handleChange('f1', 'l1', 'v1');
// filterValues = { f1: ["l1", "v1"] }

handleChange('f2', 'l2', 'v2');
// filterValues = {
//   f1: ["l1", "v1"],
//   f2: ["l2", "v2"],
// }

handleChange('f1', 'l3', 'v3');
// filterValues = {
//   f1: ["l3", "v3"],
//   f2: ["l2", "v2"],
// }
```

Demo:

```js
//const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useState({ f1: ["l","v"] });

// Manual mock for useState return values
let filterValues = { f1: ["l","v"] };
setFilterValues = stateUpdater => filterValues = stateUpdater(filterValues);

const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
  setFilterValues(prevFilterValues => ({
    ...prevFilterValues,  // copy previous state
    [filter]: [label, value], // set the value for filter key
  }));
};

// Start Demo
console.log('initial filterValues', filterValues); // { f1: ["l", "v"] }

handleChange('f1', 'l1', 'v1');
console.log('filterValues', filterValues); // { f1: ["l1", "v1"] }

handleChange('f2', 'l2', 'v2');
console.log('filterValues', filterValues); // { f1: ["l1", "v1"], f2: ["l2", "v2"] }

handleChange('f1', 'l3', 'v3');
console.log('filterValues', filterValues); // { f1: ["l3", "v3"], f2: ["l2", "v2"] }
```

Comment: ```
handleChange('f2', 'ls', 'vb');
{
  {f1: ['l', 'b']},
   f2: ["ls", "vb"]
}
```
Is this you required output? Coz from above function, this is what I get.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be finding the right object and changing its value before setting the state:

```
const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
   const currentFilters = [...filterValues] // A new copy of the state.
   const newFilters = currentFilters.map(stateFilter => stateFilter[filter] ? {[filter]: [label, value]} : stateFilter)
   setFilterValues(newFilters);
 };
```

While I believe this solves your case, I think it would be better if you stored your filters in an array, meanning an object structure of:

```
[[l1,v1], [l1, v2]]
```

That way, filter one is just index 0 on your filter array, and so on. So to do what you want, you will have a function that receives a filter number, label and value:

```
const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
   let newFilters = [...filterValues] // A new copy of the state.
   newFilters[filter - 1] = [label, value];
   setFilterValues(newFilters);
 };
```

Please note that if you receive a filter number of 1, meanning the first filter, you want to access place 0 on the filters array.

Comment: thanks, for your answer, but now it doest update state when i use the object solution and the array version is not working i think, because i need o be able to update filters , that have been added earlier, not only  the last one and i also need the "filter" string that gets send to handleChange. introducing a newfilter object or array however might be a step towards the solution. so thanks again!

Comment: I had a type in the object solution, please try again, By the way, both these examples will work asuming `filter` is f1/f2/etc... (or 1, 2, 3 in the array case)

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChange = (filter, label, value) => {
    filterValues.map(el => {
      for (let keys in el) {
        if (keys === filter) {
          el[filter] = [label, value];
          setFilterValues([el]);
        } else {
          let newObj = { [filter]: [label, value] };
          let finalArr = [...filterValues, newObj];
          setFilterValues(finalArr);
        }
      }
    });
  };
```